# How to register custom server control on ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols, asp.net-controls, asp.net-customcontrol

I have a project and I am trying to register a custom server control (there is no `.ascx` file) on the page.  I am currently using

### Class Declaration

```
namespace MyApp.Controls{
    public class CustomControl: WebControl{
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }        
        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(Text);
        }
    }
}
```

On my page,

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myControls" Namespace="MyApp.Controls" %>
<myControls:CustomControl runat="server" Text="What up!" />
```

I receive a Parser Error, with the message **"Unknown server tag 'myControls:CustomControl'."**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need assembly too.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, if this control is in another class library, or even if it's in the same one, it wouldn't be a bad idea to specify control's assembly in @Register:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myControls" Namespace="MyApp.Controls" Assembly="MyApp" %>
<myControls:CustomControl runat="server" Text="What's up!" />
```

Clean and rebuild your solution too in order to verify everything is compiled rightly!

Comment: No problem! Great to know you got it :)

Comment: Just wondering, why using `Src` instead of `Assembly` does not work? Does this mean I need to compile my source and put the dll in bin folder? `Src` works with user control.

Comment: @CookieMonster Well, you don't put the DLL in the bin folder manually.... Do you imagine using `Src` in order to tell that a regular C# class is the control? And what about the dependencies, where are coming from? Using `Src` would defeat the point of coding server controls.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you may need to specify the strong name for the assembly, which you can get by examining the assembly in the GAC. Example: assembly="MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5499f3feedc0ffee" instead of only assembly="MyApp".

Answer (score 8):

If your control will be reused on several pages, you may want to register it in web.config, as one of system.web/pages/controls subelements instead of copy-pasting the same <@Register tag in all affected pages.

**web.config:**

```
<system.web>
  <pages ...>
    <controls>
      ...
      <add tagPrefix="myCompany" namespace="MyCompany.Whatever.Controls" assembly="Whatever"/>
    </controls>
```

**thepage.aspx:**

```
<myCompany:ControlClassName ID="TheStuff" runat="server" ... />
```

Answer (score 6):

You should put your control either under the `App_Code` folder (in the case if the control not in assembly) or add a reference to assembly where this control is:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myControls" Namespace="MyApp.Controls"
      Assembly="SomeAssembly" %>
```

But guessing, your control not under the `App_Code` folder.

Comment: Yup, more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: I got it to work by adding the Assembly attribute.  Placing the code file in App_Code was not necessary

Answer (score 5):

Add an assembly attribute to your register tag