# ASP.NET: Is there a way to put all the new web User Controls under the same Namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I know this is probably a simple question but, I have a ASP.NET WebSite not WebApplication and I'm trying to get all of my Web User Controls under the same namespace so that I can register them once inside the web.config file and be done with it.

My Question is, How do I do this (put them all under the same namespace and make it the default namespace for that folder)?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Hiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look in following link...You will definately get your answer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164640.aspx

[ASP.NET: Register multiple controls at once via namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183376/asp-net-register-multiple-controls-at-once-via-namespace)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for responding, I have done that already with no luck, I went ahead and wrapped my code behind in a namespace called "MyNamespace" and Registered it in the System.Web/Page/Controls with a tagprefix of uc2 (<add tagPrefix="uc2" namespace="MyNamespace"/>). Unfortunately, when I go back to the page it says "element 'news' is not a known element...."

I should also mention again that I am on WebSite not WebApplication.

Once again, Thank you,
Hiva